# How to get the json data in this site in python 3?

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My work is basically:

-Entering in this website "https://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/preenchimento_municipio_cras_new1.php"

-Fill the 2 forms (with `AC - Acre` and `Bujari`, for example)

-Click on "Dados Detalhados"(detailed data) in the last column of the table generated. (When you click on "Dados Detalhados", it will generate a second table with the data of 1 month per row).

-Access the data generated by the second table clicking in "Visualizar Relatório" in the last column of each row. <---- THATS the data I'm trying to scrape. But it is a dynamic website and I can't get the data just accessing the `url2` (when you click in 'Visualizar relatório' the website returns to the initial url but with the tables I want to scrape). Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/preenchimento_municipio_cras_new1.php'
params ={
    'uf_ibge': '12',
    'nome_estado': 'AC - Acre'
    'p_ibge': '1200138'
    'nome_municipio': 'Bujari'    
}


r = requests.post(url, params = params, verify = False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
tables = pd.read_html(r.text)
unidades = tables[1]
print(unidades)


url2 = 'http://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/rel_preenchidos_cras.php?&p_id_cras=12001301971'
params2 ={
    'p_id_cras': '12001301971'
    'mes_referencia': '2019-02-01'
}
r2 = requests.post(url2, json = params2, verify = False)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'lxml')

soup2
```

Note that `url2` is the url generated when you click in "Dados Detalhados" and it has the 'p_id_cras' as the second dictionary.

`params2` should be the dict used to scrape that data I'm talking about. I've tried the commands `params`, `data` and `json` in the second post request, but none of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url2` should use `GET` without parameters.
And then you have page with table with links which have `href="javascript:"`
but also `onclick='enviadados(12001301971,"2019-02-01")'`
so you have your parameters for next request.

Last request uses `POST` with parameters `12001301971,2019-02-01` and url

https://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/visualiza_preenchimento_cras.php'`

My code. I hope it works correclty.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
import pandas as pd

base = 'http://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/'

url = base + 'preenchimento_municipio_cras_new1.php'
#print('url:', url)
params ={
    'uf_ibge': '12',
    'nome_estado': 'AC - Acre',
    'p_ibge': '1200138',
    'nome_municipio': 'Bujari'    ,
}


r = requests.post(url, params=params, verify=False)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
tables = pd.read_html(r.text)

#unidades = tables[1]
#print(unidades)

all_td1 = soup1.find('table', class_="panel-body").find_all('td')
#print('len(all_td1):', len(all_td1))
for td1 in all_td1:

    all_a1 = td1.find_all('a')[:1]
    #print('len(all_a1):', len(all_a1))
    for a1 in all_a1:

        url = base + a1['href']
        print('url:', url)

        r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        #print(soup.text)

        all_td2 = soup2.find('table', class_="panel-body").find_all('td')
        #print('len(all_td2):', len(all_td2))
        for td2 in all_td2:
            all_a2 = td2.find_all('a')
            #print('len(all_a2):', len(all_a2))
            for a2 in all_a2:
                print('onclick:', a2['onclick'])

                params = {
                    'p_id_cras': a2['onclick'][11:22], #'12001301971',
                    'mes_referencia': a2['onclick'][24:-2], #'2019-02-01',
                }

                print(params)

                url = 'https://aplicacoes.mds.gov.br/sagirmps/estrutura_fisica/visualiza_preenchimento_cras.php'
                r = requests.post(url, params=params, verify=False)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
                all_table = soup.find_all('table')
                print(all_table)
```